# How does the Math.max.apply() work?

Tags: javascript, function, apply

How does the `Math.max.apply()` work?.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
      var list = ["12","23","100","34","56",
                                    "9","233"];
      console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,list));    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max

The above code finds the Max number in the List. Can anyone tell me how does the below code work?. It seems it works if i pass `null or Math.`

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math,list));
```

Does all the `user-defined/Native functions` have call and apply method which we can use?.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

`apply` accepts an array and it applies the array as parameters to the actual function. So,

```
Math.max.apply(Math, list);
```

can be understood as,

```
Math.max("12", "23", "100", "34", "56", "9", "233");
```

So, `apply` is a convenient way to pass an array of data as parameters to a function. Remember

```
console.log(Math.max(list));   # NaN
```

will not work, because `max` doesn't accept an array as input.

There is another advantage, of using `apply`, you can choose your own context. The first parameter, you pass to `apply` of any function, will be the `this` inside that function. But, `max` doesn't depend on the current context. So, anything would work in-place of `Math`.

```
console.log(Math.max.apply(undefined, list));   # 233
console.log(Math.max.apply(null, list));        # 233
console.log(Math.max.apply(Math, list));        # 233
```

Since [`apply` is actually defined in `Function.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), any valid JavaScript function object, will have `apply` function, by default.

Comment: How do say that max doesn't depend upon the current context?.

Comment: @Shane because, it works even when we set the context to `undefined` or `null` :) If `max` tried to access/change anything in the context, it would have failed when context is set to `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: The first parameter is an illusion and doesn't make sense to me. How can `Math.max.apply(Math, list);` 
convert to  `Math.max("12", "23", "100", "34", "56", "9", "233");` 
when doing `Math.max.apply(0, list);` 
or even something silly like `Math.max.apply(01231230210302302103923593, list);`
 is still equal to:
`Math.max("12", "23", "100", "34", "56", "9", "233");`

Comment: @NiCkNewman Actually, `Math.max` will not use the first parameter, since it doesn't need any context. It operates only on the data which it receives in the arguments.

Comment: Yeah, but what exactly is `apply()` passing in it's first argument? It's very confusing. Take this code for example: http://jsfiddle.net/agx85sba/4/ `GAMELENGTH4` should be returning 8, but it returns 2. It doesn't seem that `apply()`'s first parameter sends any data through and to me seems  like an illusion.

Comment: @NiCkNewman Its too broad to discuss in the comments section. But this article on [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) would be a good starting point. It also has a section [`call` and `apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#call_and_apply) which details this.

Comment: Best explanation of .apply() ever!

Comment: If `Math.max` is called with no arguments it returnes negative Infinity so I would use `Math.max.apply(-Infinity, list);`. Also you risk exceeding the JavaScript engine's argument length limit with `apply()`.

Comment: @A1rPun I don't see any advantage in adding -Infinity as the first argument with an empty array, if you have more info on that, that would be great, here's an example showing null and -Infinity resulting in the same output: https://codepen.io/pythagoras1357/pen/BrBwwM

Comment: Why null or math ?

Answer (score 46):

On JavaScript ES6 just use the [Spread operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31035825/1074519):

```
var list = ["12","23","100","34","56","9","233"];
console.log(Math.max(...list));
//                   ^^^ Spread operator
```

Comment: To check the "Spread operator" compatibility: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-spread_(...)_operator

Answer (score 18):

> Can anyone tell me how does the below code work?

```
Math.max.apply(Math,list)
```

Invokes a `Math.max` function with `Math` object to be used as a `this` reference in the function implementation (body) and `list` to be passed as an arguments.

So this eventually equals to

```
Math.max("12","23","100","34","56", "9","233")
```

> It seems it works if i pass null or Math.

Obviously `Math.max` implementation doesn't use instance variable - there is no reason to do so. The native implementation would just iterate over `arguments` and find the maximum one.

> Does all the user-defined/Native functions have call and apply method which we can use?.

Yes, every single function can be invoked using `call` or `apply`

References:

- [MDN `.apply()` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) (credits to [@RGraham](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571194/rgraham))

Answer (score 6):

I will start by saying `Math.max(...numbers)` and `Function.prototype.apply()` should only be used for arrays with relatively few elements. (...) and apply will either fail or return the wrong result if the array is too large

`Math.max.apply(null | undefined | Math, numbers)` is the same as `Math.max(...numbers)` so I would recommend `Math.max(...numbers)` for aesthetic reasons.

```js
const numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];

const max = Math.max(...numbers);

console.log('max:', max);
// expected output: 7

const min = Math.min(...numbers);

console.log('min:', min);
// expected output: 2
```

**If you need to find the maximum element in a numeric array that is very large:** use the `Array.reduce()` method.

`Array.reduce()` can be used to find the maximum element in a numeric array, by comparing each value:

```js
const numbers = [5, 6, 2, 3, 7];
const getMax = (numbers) => numbers.reduce((a, b) => Math.max(a, b));

const getMin = (numbers) => numbers.reduce((a, b) => Math.min(a, b));
 
const max = getMax(numbers)
const min = getMin(numbers)

console.log('max:', max)
console.log('min:', min)
```

**Conclusion:**

Numeric array that is relatively small: use `Math.max(...numbers)`
Numeric array that is very large: use the `Array.reduce()` method

Comment: The JavaScriptCore engine has hard-coded argument limit of 65536, so when using apply() you should make sure that your array size will always be lesser.

Answer (score 3):

### Math.max(val1, val2,...)

`Math.max(1, 2, 3); // Math.max([value1[, value2[, ...]]])`
`value1, value2...` are parameters and must be Numbers [MDN Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

You can't pass `array` as `Math.max` parameters. To pass an array you have to use `apply`.

### Apply

The first parameter of apply is `this`, the second is `array`.
Math methods are equivalent of static in other languages, which means it doesn't need an object instance unlike to `array.prototype.slice` so you don't need to pass `this` in this case.

Example

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3];

Math.max(1, 2, 3);  // -> 3
Math.max(arr);      // -> NaN (Not a Number)
Math.max.apply(null, arr);  // Math.max.apply(null, [1, 2, 3]) -> Math.max(1, 2, 3) -> 3

arr.slice(1);  // -> returns Array [2, 3]
Array.prototype.slice.call(arr, 1); // Array.prototype.slice.call([1, 2, 3], 1) == [1, 2, 3].slice(1)
```

When you want to pass an array as parameter you have to use `apply`, otherwise use `call`.

**a**pply = **a**rray
**c**all = **c**omma separated
[More about call & apply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986896/what-is-the-difference-between-call-and-apply#1986909)