# Why should you pass Math as the first argument to Math.max.apply?

Tags: javascript

I'm going through John Resig's JavaScript ninja tutorial and on [#51](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#51) I see this:

```
// Find the largest number in that array of arguments 
var largestAllButFirst = Math.max.apply( Math, allButFirst );
```

`allButFirst` is just a small array of integers.  I believe I understand what `apply` does, but I can't understand why `Math` is being passed as an argument to `apply`.

Answer (score 3):

The first parameter of the `.apply` is the context. Inside the function body the `this` keyword will reference that value.

Example:

```
function sum(a){ return this + a; }
sum.apply(1, [1]); // will return 2
// or with .call
sum.call(1, 1); // also returns 2
```

By default if you call `Math.max` the context (the `this` keyword) is automatically set to `Math`. To keep this behavior `Math` is passed as the first parameter in apply.

Comment: Scope has nothing to do with `this`. Those are two different things.

Answer (score 1):

Passing it `Math` is not necessary, anything will work here. `Math` indicates the context of the operation, however `max` does not require a context. This means that `Math.max.apply(undefined, allButFirst)` will also work. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21255326/3352674) answer.

Comment: @JakeSellers For `Math.max` specifically, and I'm sure a few other functions, it really doesn't matter. The point is that `Math.max` **doesn't rely on or use the `this` value**...but many other function **do**. While it's technically optional, I would suggest always passing it, because you **normally** call it like `Math.max()` (the `this` value is `Math`). I'd rather be safe than sorry for such a little thing, as well as consistent.

Comment: @ian in [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) for arguments, you can see they use `Array.prototype.slice.call(arugments)` to change the args into an array with no context given to call.  What is your opinion on this?  I use this technique sometimes, should I not worry about it or pass a context, perhaps just `this` for the local function context?

Comment: @JakeSellers That is a little different. `slice` requires the `this` value to be set to an array (or array-like object, like `arguments`). Since `arguments` isn't an array, it doesn't have a `slice` method. But since it's array-like (has a `length` property), you can call `Array.prototype.slice` and provide an array-like object as `this` (that's what the `.call()` is for). Like I said for `Math.max` - it **doesn't** use `this`

Comment: @JakeSellers: In that case `arguments` becomes `this` inside the function. It's like calling `arguments.slice()` **iff** arguments was an array. The first argument passed to `.call` or `.apply` is always the value `this` will refer to inside the function.

Comment: @FelixKling ok I think all the pieces fit together now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

> fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
>
> **thisArg:** The value of this provided for the call to fun. Note that this
>   may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a
>   function in non-strict mode code, null and undefined will be replaced
>   with the global object, and primitive values will be boxed.

So, in your example, `Math` is being used as the context for the function (if the keyword `this` is used inside).

If no `thisArg` is used, then the default is the global object.  So, it is good practice to give some context if possible.