# Having trouble finding the largest numbers in a subarray

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is my current code:

```
var largestNumbers = new Array(4);

function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var biggest = Math.max.apply(null, largestOfFour) 
    for (var index in arr) {
        for(var i=0; i < arr[index].length; i++){
            if (arr[index] > biggest){
                arr[index].push(largestNumbers);
            }
            else if (arr[index] < biggest) {
                arr[index].splice(0, 1);
            }
        }
    }
    return largestNumbers;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

My objective is to find the largest number in each of the subarrays and then put those values into another array and then return that value. I have been searching around for things like "How to extract a subarray from array" and that has led to me using the splice function. I'm not sure if I'm using it right, but I'm trying everything I've got because I've been stuck on this problem for 2 days now. If anyone could just lead me in the path to solve this problem, I would be more than grateful. Thank you all so much.

Furthermore, I was using this site to try and guide me along. There is a snippet of code that attempts to resolve a problem similar to mine in the latter half of the page. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var largest = function largest(arr) {
    return arr.map(function(arr) {
        return Math.max.apply(null, arr);
    });
};
```

[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jeffshaver/y1jt5edk/)

Comment: plus one, nice and compact ;)

Answer (score 1):

- Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new Array by looping over the first level.
- Use  [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max) to get the maximum value from a list of numbers
- Use [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) to convert the array to arguments in Math.max

```js
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  return arr.map(function(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(Math, array)
  });
}

var myArray = [
  [4, 5, 1, 3],
  [13, 27, 18, 26],
  [32, 35, 37, 39],
  [1000, 1001, 857, 1]
];
console.log(largestOfFour(myArray));
```

Comment: Same answer posted below

Comment: And it was not there when I started to answer it. Congrats on being first.

Comment: @epascarello: OI, I was first! You watch where you throw around that Congrats of yours

Comment: @musefan you were not the first with this type of solution. ;)

Comment: @epascarello: pfft.. well mine's bigger than yours!

Comment: I can make it bigger by adding more line breaks. ;)

Comment: Does that work? I'll have to give it a try when I get home

Comment: Plus one... so it's even more like Jeff's

Comment: @epascarello Can you please explain the reason for putting 'Math' in the first parameter for your apply function? I'm having trouble understanding what needs to go there.

Comment: @ChasenBettinger In this case anything that is valid can go in the first parameter of the apply since `Math.max` uses no context. Some people use `null` and others use `Math`. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work) has an explanation that might help you understand.

Comment: @epascarello Yes, that does help me! Thank you so much. I hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Applying simple nested loop's logic.

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

var maxArray = [];

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

var maxE = 0;

   for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {

      if(maxE < arr[i][j]) {

      maxE = arr[i][j];

   }

 }

   maxArray.push(maxE);

 }
  arr = maxArray;
  return arr;

 }

 largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

OR Try this

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {

var maxArray = [];


for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

 var maxE = Math.max(...arr[i]);          // this spread is only available in ES6 so can be  replaced by --> Math.max.apply(null, arr[i])

  maxArray.push(maxE);
}

arr = maxArray;

return arr;

}


 largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do it with a simple nested loop. Find the biggest number for each inner array and add it to the result:

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    var result = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var max = 0;
        var inner = arr[i];
        for(var j = 0; j < inner.length; j++){
            if(inner[j] > max)
                max = inner[j];
        }
        result.push(max);
    }

    return result;
}

var output = largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
// [5, 27, 39, 1001]
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/rpmvyhrh/)

Answer (score 0):

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
    return arr.reduce(function(p, c, index, arr){
        p.push(Math.max.apply(null, c));
        return p;
    }, []);
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can code like this also , creating a new array showing in them also

```
function largestOfFour(arr) {
  // You can do this!
  var newArray=[];
  for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    newArray.push(Math.max.apply(Math,arr[i]));

  }
  return newArray;
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var largestNumbers = new Array();

function largestOfFour(arr) {
    for (var i = 0 ; i< arr.length; i ++) {
        largestNumbers.push(Math.max.apply(Math, arr[i]));   
    }
}

largestOfFour([[4, 5, 1, 3], [13, 27, 18, 26], [32, 35, 37, 39], [1000, 1001, 857, 1]]);
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a function that updates a global variable. Would be better for it to return the result, or modify an argument passed in. Still, it _does_ work so can't downvote it

Answer (score -1):

Using the approach with Math.max.apply() you can do that with one loop that iterates through the array as argument;

```
function largestOfFour(arr){
   var result = [];

  for(var i = 0 ; i < arr.length ; i++){
    result[i] = Math.max.apply(null, arr[i]);
  }

  return result; 
}
```

EDIT: 
As @Jeff Shaver posted a [simpler solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31612127/having-trouble-finding-the-largest-numbers-in-a-subarray/31612455#31612455), you should use the [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function to return the result array.