# Set max y axis point 10% greater than current max - Highcharts

Tags: jquery, highcharts

In this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/ot24zrkt/122/

The y axis is set to :

```
    max : 50,
    min : 0
```

But how to set the max y axis values to 10% greater than the current max Y axis value. So the max y axis value on fiddle is 34, can a new point which has value 34 + (10% of 34) be added, instead of hardcoding what the max value should be ?

fiddle code :

```
HTML : 

<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container2" style="width:500px;height:400px;margin:1.5em 1em;"></div>

<script>
var d          = new Date();
var pointStart = d.getTime();
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global: {
        useUTC:false
    },
    colors: [
        'rgba( 0,   154, 253, 0.9 )', //bright blue
        'rgba( 253, 99,  0,   0.9 )', //bright orange
        'rgba( 40,  40,  56,  0.9 )', //dark
        'rgba( 253, 0,   154, 0.9 )', //bright pink
        'rgba( 154, 253, 0,   0.9 )', //bright green
        'rgba( 145, 44,  138, 0.9 )', //mid purple
        'rgba( 45,  47,  238, 0.9 )', //mid blue
        'rgba( 177, 69,  0,   0.9 )', //dark orange
        'rgba( 140, 140, 156, 0.9 )', //mid
        'rgba( 238, 46,  47,  0.9 )', //mid red
        'rgba( 44,  145, 51,  0.9 )', //mid green
        'rgba( 103, 16,  192, 0.9 )'  //dark purple
    ],
    chart: {
        alignTicks:false,
        type:'',
        margin:[60,25,100,90],
        //borderRadius:10,
        //borderWidth:1,
        //borderColor:'rgba(156,156,156,.25)',
        //backgroundColor:'rgba(204,204,204,.25)',
        //plotBackgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        style: {
            fontFamily: 'Abel,serif'
        }
    },
    title: {
        text:'Test Chart Title',
        align:'left',
        margin:10,
        x: 50,
        style: {
            fontWeight:'bold',
            color:'rgba(0,0,0,.9)'
        }
    },
    subtitle: {
        text:'Test Chart Subtitle',   
        align:'left',
        x: 52,
    },
    legend: { enabled: true },
    plotOptions: {
        area: {
            lineWidth:1,
            marker: {
                enabled:false,
                symbol:'circle',
                radius:4
            }
        },
        arearange: {
            lineWidth:1
        },
        areaspline: {
            lineWidth:1,
            marker: {
                enabled:false,
                symbol:'circle',
                radius:4
            }
        },
        areasplinerange: {
            lineWidth:1
        },
        boxplot: {
            groupPadding:0.05,
            pointPadding:0.05,
            fillColor:'rgba(255,255,255,.75)'
        },
        bubble: {
            minSize:'0.25%',
            maxSize:'17%'
        },
        column: {
            //stacking:'normal',
            groupPadding:0.05,
            pointPadding:0.05
        },
        columnrange: {
            groupPadding:0.05,
            pointPadding:0.05
        },
        errorbar: {
            groupPadding:0.05,
            pointPadding:0.05,
            showInLegend:true        
        },
        line: {
            lineWidth:1,
            marker: {
                enabled:false,
                symbol:'circle',
                radius:4
            }
        },
        scatter: {
            marker: {
                symbol: 'circle',
                radius:5
            }
        },
        spline: {
            lineWidth:1,
            marker: {
                enabled:false,
                symbol:'circle',
                radius:4
            }
        },
        series: {
            shadow: false,
            borderWidth:0,
            states: {
                hover: {
                    lineWidthPlus:0,
                }
            }
        }
    },
    xAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'X Axis Title',
            rotation:0,
            textAlign:'center',
            style:{ 
                color:'rgba(0,0,0,.9)'
            }
        },
        labels: { 
            style: {
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.9)',
                fontSize:'9px'
            }
        },
        lineWidth:.5,
        lineColor:'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
        tickWidth:.5,
        tickLength:3,
        tickColor:'rgba(0,0,0,.75)'
    },
    yAxis: {
        minPadding:0,
        maxPadding:0,
        gridLineColor:'rgba(204,204,204,.25)',
        gridLineWidth:0.5,
        title: { 
            text: 'Y Axis<br/>Title',
            rotation:0,
            textAlign:'right',
            style:{ 
                color:'rgba(0,0,0,.9)',
            }
        },
        labels: { 
            style: {
                color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.9)',
                fontSize:'9px'
            }
        },
        lineWidth:.5,
        lineColor:'rgba(0,0,0,.5)',
        tickWidth:.5,
        tickLength:3,
        tickColor:'rgba(0,0,0,.75)'
    }
}); 


</script>

CSS : 

@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Changa+One|Loved+by+the+King|Fredericka+the+Great|Droid+Serif:400,700,400italic|Abel|Oswald:400,300,700);

body {
    font-family:Abel, Calibri, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:95%;
}

JavaScript : 

var chart;
var pointStart = Date.UTC(2014,0,1);
$(function() {

    $('#container2').highcharts({
        chart       : { type    : 'line' },
        title       : { },
        subtitle    : { },
        legend      : { enabled : true },
        tooltip     : { },
        plotOptions : {
            series  : {
                pointStart      : pointStart,
                pointInterval   : 24 * 3600 * 1000*30
            }
        },
        xAxis      : { 
            min:Date.UTC(2014, 0, 0),
            max:Date.UTC(2014, 11, 1),
            //allowDecimals: false,
            type           : 'datetime',
            tickInterval   : 24 * 3600 * 1000*30, //one day
            labels         : {
                rotation : 0
            },

        },
        yAxis      : { 
            max : 50,
            min : 0
        }
    }); 
    chart = $('#container2').highcharts();


var jsonString = '[ { "date": "2014-1-01", "in": "30", "out": "21" }, { "date": "2014-1-02", "in": "35", "out": "32" }, { "date": "2014-1-03", "in": "23", "out": "34" }, { "date": "2014-1-04", "in": "20", "out": "15" }, { "date": "2014-1-05", "in": "34", "out": "20" }, { "date": "2014-2-06", "in": "22", "out": "34" }, { "date": "2014-2-07", "in": "15", "out": "18" } ]';

var myData = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var dataArray = []

$.each(myData, function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.date)
    var d = new Date(obj.date)
   dataArray.push([Date.parse(d), parseInt(obj.in)])
});

    chart.addSeries({ 
        data: dataArray    
    });

    console.log('data is '+dataArray)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

consider the following:

```
var temp=[]
var height=0;
$.each(myData, function(i, obj) {
    console.log(obj.date)
    var d = new Date(obj.date)
   dataArray.push([Date.parse(d), parseInt(obj.in)])
   temp.push(parseInt(obj.in))
});

    height=Math.max.apply(Math, temp);
    height=height/10+height;
    //alert(height);
```

in charts:

```
yAxis      : { 
            max : height,
            min : 0
        }
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ot24zrkt/124/)

hoping this is what you are looking for

Comment: thanks, why pass Math as first argument to function Math.max.apply ?

Comment: for math.max.apply,refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work

Answer (score 0):

Determine the maximum value within the `$.each()` method.

Then call [**`setExtremes()`**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Axis.setExtremes) on the first (and only) yAxis:

```
var maxy= 0;
$.each(myData, function(i, obj) {
   var d = new Date(obj.date)
   dataArray.push([Date.parse(d), parseInt(obj.in)])
   maxy= Math.max(maxy, obj.in);
});
chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(0, maxy*1.10);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4mfe3xd/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickPositioner which allows to return custom ticks positions.

```
tickPositioner: function(min, max) {
            var positions = [1,2,3],
                maxPercent = max + 0.1 * max,
                tick = 0,
                increment = Math.ceil(maxPercent / 6) ;

            for (tick; tick <= max; tick += increment) {
                positions.push(tick);
            }

            positions.push(maxPercent);

            return positions;
        }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ot24zrkt/126/