# Javascript function parameters as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Say for example I want the largest number out of an array of numbers.

```
var numbers = [54,34,76,33,87,12,76,92,44,93,23];
```

I want to be able to use `Math.max()` to find the largest number without using `eval`.

So, I want to be able to pass an array of parameters to a function. The array's length can change, so `Math.max(numbers[0],numbers[1]...)` won't work.

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.apply()` method:

```
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, numbers);
```

The `.apply()` method is a property of `Function.prototype` and so is available on all function instances. Its first argument is used as the value of `this` in the function to be called, and the second argument should be an array that will be used as the list of parameter values.

In my example above I used `Math` as the value for `this`, because that's what `this` will be in a typical invocation of `Math.max`, but (on my installation of Firefox at least) `Math.max.apply(null, numbers);` works too.

Comment: Also, you can use the spread operator if you're working with JavaScript Harmony **ES6**, check my recent [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32429627/1074519)