# use of Javascript math.max.apply(null or math..)

Tags: javascript, apply

**First example**

```
var arr1 = ['a', 'b'];
var arr2 = ['c', 'd'];

arr1.push.apply(arr1, arr2);
    // arr1 is now ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
```

**second example**

```
Math.max.apply(null, [-1, 5, 11, 3])
```

In the first one above, can we just use `array1.push(array2)`, is there any different?

In the second one above, the null param really confusing to me and what's more, it seems that max mehood need number type, not an array?

Comment: 1. no. that would put a reference to that array in `arr1`. 2. math.max can take any number  - this just allows you to call it with an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use `arr1.push(arr2)`, the result is different:

```
['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']]
```

To get the same result as your original `arr1.push.apply`, you would have to do

```
arr1.concat(arr2);
```

`apply` takes the array argument and turns each element into a separate argument to the function being called. When you call the function normally, the array is just a single argument.

The normal way to call `Math.max` is with each number that it's comparing as a separate argument:

```
Math.max(-1, 5, 11, 3);
```

In order to get the arguments from an array, you have to use `apply` to spread them.

The reason for the `null` argument to in the second case is because the first argument to `apply` is the *context* of the function, i.e. the value that will be assigned to `this` inside the function. When you call a function normally, the context is the value before the `.`; for example, when you write

```
arr1.push('x');
```

the context is the `arr1` array. `Math.max()` doesn't use its context, but you have to pass something, so `null` is a common placeholder. But when we call `push` using `apply`, we have to pass `arr1` as the context, so it knows which array to modify. Some people like to write

```
Math.max.apply(Math, [-1, 5, 11, 3]);
```

so that the context will be the same as if you'd called `Math.max` in the normal way. But it doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: so why we can use just  Math.max(-1, 5, 11, 3)  rather than Math.max.apply(Math, [-1, 5, 11, 3]). what the point of using Math.max.apply(Math, [-1, 5, 11, 3])?

Comment: You wouldn't use it with a literal array, you would use it when you have the array in a variable that you filled in dynamically.  Your code is just an example.

Comment: cool,I am wondering why you are saying that 'apply takes the array argument and turns each element into a separate argument to the function being called'?

Comment: `someFunction.apply(null, [1, 2, 3])` is equivalent to `someFunction(1, 2, 3)`. Each element of the array becomes a separate argument to the function.

Comment: Okay, really appreciate for yr time

Answer (score 1):

`f.apply(x, y)` is `x.f(`the contents of `y)`.

Where `f` is `arr1.push`, `x` is `arr1`, and `y` is `arr2`,
that's `arr1.push.apply(arr1, arr2)` is `arr1.push(the contents of arr2)`.

Note, `arr1.push` adds all its arguments to `arr1`, so `arr1.push(arr2)` adds `arr2` to `arr1`, making it `['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']]`.

Where `f` is `Math.max`, and `y` is `[-1, 5, 11, 3]`,
that's `Math.max.apply(x, [-1, 5, 11, 3])`.

But what do you put in `x`?

`Math.max` is made to work as function called on its own, not as a method of an object.

If you leave out `x` and do `Math.max.apply([-1, 5, 11, 3])`, `Math.max` will think it's being called as a method of the array and without any arguments.
So it will give the result of `Math.max()`.

So then you have to put something in the `x`, and it doesn't matter what, because `Math.max` is not made to use it, so it will ignore it.

The best value you can give `x` is the simplest, which is `null`.

If you're wondering what a line of Javascript code will do, it's a good idea to test it.

Firefox and Chrome both have a built-in Javascript command-line you can use, and there are websites that do Javascript command-lines too.
I used Firefox > Tools > Web Developer > Web Console to check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. you will add the second array as a value of the first ([a,b,[c,d]]). If you want to merge both array I suggest you to call [.concat](http://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/array/concat) instead
2. The first argument in "apply" and "call" defines the context used when the function is called: the "this". For math.max the context is not important and therefore the context can be null, you can pass Math as well which in my opinion would be more semantically correct. But it does not matter in this case

Comment: And can we just use array1.push(array2) and why the second parameter is the array in the max method?

Comment: array.apply(array,[1,2,3,4]) is equivalent to array.push(1,2,3,4) (see partial application) which is different than array.push([1,2,3,4]) 
The second argument in Math.max.apply are the arguments you want to partially apply, it will be equivalent to Math.max(-1,5,11,3). I think the key word you need to search is partial application

Answer (score 0):

**first example**

`array1.push(array2)`

`array1` becomes `['a', 'b', ['c', 'd']]`

**second example**

See thefoureye's explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work)

Namely:

> There is another advantage, of using apply, you can choose your own
>   context. The first parameter, you pass to apply of any function, will
>   be the this inside that function. But, max doesn't depend on the
>   current context. So, anything would work in-place of Math.