# Two conditions in for loop

Tags: javascript, loops

I have this code which im echoing data from jquery success .

```
   for(i = 0;i < dat.id.length; i++){

           // im echoing data here 
    }
```

and i want check for the highest value in `dat.voteup`

like that (It works)

```
    var maxvoteup = 0; 
    if (dat.voteup[i] - dat.votedown[i] ==maxvoteup) {
                    console.log(maxvoteup);
        //i want fetch maxvoteup here

     }
```

But i want make just one For loop not two . How can i do that pls?

EDIT:

```
  var maxvoteup = 0; 
    for (i = 0;i < (dat.voteup-dat.votedown).length ;i++) {
         if (dat.voteup[i] - dat.votedown[i]>maxvoteup) {
            maxvoteup = dat.voteup[i] - dat.votedown[i];
                    console.log(maxvoteup);
        //i want fetch maxvoteup here
      }
     }
```

EDIT2:
this is what im getting in my jquery response , But actually my max vote is 10 not 8 . 8 is just voted up to 8 , but there is other votes which is 10.

```
   {"status":"success","message":[],"date_edited":[2016-04-21 21:31:25],"voteup":[],"votedown":[8],"id":[]}
```

Comment: you just use both condition inside single for loop .store both result in different variable or   array.

Comment: @Tushar  sorry for my late answer, maybe i was not clear, i edited my question. i mean i have for loop also to look for max value. how do i combine that with the first for loop

Answer (score 1):

Your code is a little hard to read, but if I understand correctly I believe all you need to do is combine both into a single loop with `maxvoteup` defined outside.

```
var maxvoteup = 0;
for(i = 0;i < dat.id.length; i++){
    // echo data...

    // max upvote
    if (dat.voteup[i] - dat.votedown[i] == maxvoteup) {
      console.log(maxvoteup);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Unfortunately getting the maximum value from a list requires you to iterate through the list, i.e., a maximum value **cannot** be found in constant time.  I suggest you first find the maximum, and then proceed with your for loop.

Also, if you know your maximum is a list of numbers, you can actually use Javascript's `apply` to make the code a little cleaner:

```
var maxvoteup = Math.max.apply(Math, listOfMaxVotes);
```

See here: [How does the Math.max.apply() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work)

EDIT2:

If you want to continuously keep track of the maximum, then all you need to do is move the `maxvoteup` variable to **outside** of your response handlers so you can always keep track.

```
// global scope...
var maxvoteup = 0;

// your jquery response handler
var onSuccessData = function(data) {
  // get the highest possible max from the `voteup` and `votedown` lists
  var responseMax = Math.max.apply(Math, data.voteup.concat(data.votedown));

  // check if it's greater than our global maxvoteup
  if (responseMax > maxvoteup) {
    // if it is, then update our global `maxvoteup` to the new value
    maxvoteup = responseMax;
  }

  // continue with your other processing...
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: Can you edit your question and give an example of what your jquery success data looks like? That will help a lot.

Comment: i edited my question dear smaili . im getting just the edited values not all values

Comment: I don't understand...how can your maxvote be 10 if the response has 8?

Comment: i want to highlight the message having maxvote . some messsage is beeing voted to 8 , but actually there is other message which is voted to 10 . so i want to highlight that message not the one with 8. the one with 8 is just geting voted up but its not max .

Comment: I've added a second edit.  If that answers your question, then please mark my answer.  Otherwise, you probably need additional help that is outside the scope of your question.

Comment: I think i was wrong with my idea , because im not getting back the maxvalue to compare . i think i have to edit my jquery response and add max value to bring it back from database and then i can compare if its max or not. .

Comment: But anyway +1 for the math max i will use it when i get the maxvalue from database , thanks