# Why do we have to pass 'this' to 'apply'

Tags: javascript

In

```
var values = [1,2,3,4,5];
var max = Math.max.apply(Math, values);
```

Why do we have to pass in `Math` as the `this` object? I have a hard time understanding this.

Is there anything specifically that `apply` needs `this`(`Math`) for in its execution?

Comment: No, and you don’t have to pass it. `Math.max.apply(null, values)` will work fine.

Comment: Since the method doesn't use `this` internally, actually you can pass anything there.

Comment: In this case you don't need to, since `Math.max` does need `this`, so even `null` will also work.

Comment: Interesting, because in Nicholas Zakas' book on Javascript he writes that we need to pass it: 
"The key to this technique is to pass in the Math object as the first argument of apply() so that the
this value is set appropriately. Then you can pass an array in as the second argument." Maybe this is dated information since the book is from 2012.

Comment: @Sandi: It guarantees that the call is exactly equivalent to `Math.max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)` (since that call has an object of `Math`, like any other `x.y()` call), but I can’t imagine any implementation choosing to break on `var max = Math.max; max(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. It should be forbidden to break by the standard (that’s how I would read it – there’s no specific note about it, but nothing references `this` values, and “it didn’t say *not* to break while following the standard steps” doesn’t sound very standards-compliant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply()` method (`Function.prototype.apply()`) allows you to pass arguments as an array to a function as well as the context through this.

```
func.appy(this, [argumentarray])
```

In this case, `max` doesn't need or use the current context so you could put anything and it will work, including null.

See this question:  [How does the Math.max.apply() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the internal implementation details of `max`. If it uses `this` at all and expects `this` to be `Math`, then it is required. If it doesn't use `this` in any way, it's pretty irrelevant what you pass as `thisArg`.

`max` *may* arguably use some helper methods of `Math` for its internal implementation. Unless you specifically know that it doesn't, you should preserve its context. (Generally speaking for any time you use `apply` or `call` or pass a method around.)

Comment: Okay, so if I need to do it, why is `Math` the appropriate context here rather than for example `global`?

Comment: If you call it regularly via `Math.max()`, the context is `Math` by virtue of the way you called it. So if `max` expects anything as its context, it would be `Math`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155094/discussion-on-answer-by-deceze-why-do-we-have-to-pass-this-to-apply).