# Unable to understand how Math.max.apply(null,[arrayArg]) works?

Tags: javascript

I can understand `apply` function in Javascript. But I am unable to get how does`Math.max.apply(null,[arrayArg])` work.

The definition says `apply calls the function for the given`this`value`. Here, `null` is passed as the `thisArg`. Isn't the native `Array` constructor passed as the param as `thisArg`, as `Array` constructor doesn't has the function to find the maximum/minimum number from given argument?.

Comment: Can you give a working example? The snippet in your question looks like it'd just return `Number(arrayArg)`. But in general it would allow the maximum value from an array to be selected if it were populated correctly.

Comment: How did `Array` get involved in `Math.max`? The point is that `Math.max` doesn't use `this` so it doesn't matter what you set it to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the Math.max.apply() work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255138/how-does-the-math-max-apply-work)